# Control Mac Mini via iPad

Tags: macos, ipad, remote-control, mediaplayer

To make things clear: I don’t want a way to control my mouse pointer via iPad, but insted I want to view my e;tire movie library on iPad (without it actually being stored on my iPad) and then when I choose a movie on the iPad it gets selected to my Mac Mini and played with subtitles.

What’s the optimal and easiest way to set this up? I dont care if it costs, as long as its easy and works.

Comment: Are your movies in Itunes?

Comment: Nope.  Files on a network disk.

Comment: So lets see if I have this right... you want to select the movie and press play on the iPad and it plays on the Mac mini.  Is there a reason you're against Remote Desktop to the Mac mini?  That would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: No, I'm not against it. What is it?